# Display a string inplace of a nil, datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I am trying to change the value of a cell if the value of the datetime field is nil

but it keeps changing the value to Todays date

```
            -elsif k=='pickup' || k=='delivery' || k=='Posted On'
              - if v.nil?
                = "Unknown"
              - else
                = v.strftime("%D")


Load.find(load_id).delivery.nil? 
=> true
Load.find(load_id)
=> #<Load id: 904237, length: 53, delivery: nil, pickup: "2014-09-09 17:00:00", weight: nil, equipment_id: 26, covered: false, created_at: "2014-08-18 13:21:25", updated_at: "2014-11-24 21:55:03">
```

**Actually i have narrowed it down further Guess it is not in my view...**

but actually when i pull it from the database in my controller... it is setting the @load with the default value for delivery

show controller:

```
   def show
    if params[:load]
      params[:load].delete(:type)
      params[:load][:origin] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:origin])
      params[:load][:dest] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:dest])
      @load = Load.new(params[:load])
      @load.updated_at = Time.now
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your load to appear in search results.'
    else
      @load = Load.find(params[:id])
      current_location(@load)
      @return_hotloads = Hotload.return_hotloads(@load)
      @return_loads = Load.return_loads(@load)
    end
    authorize! :show, @load
  end
```

delivery should be nil

```
@load 
=>      
#<Load id: 904237, user_id: 10640, delivery: "2015-02-13 21:48:21", pickup: "2014-09-09 17:00:00", weight: nil, tracking: nil>
```

but if i do this in the view it shows blank like i want:

```
            -elsif k=='delivery'
              - l = Load.find(@load.id).delivery
              - if l
                = l.strftime("%D")
```

witch is really strange....

[image]

Comment: - @load.attributes.each do |k,v|

Comment: Can you post the entire code block as well as the code for the view?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown that explains the behavior you're seeing. I'm guessing that there's something else in your model that's setting the attribute to a default value that you're not expecting. Show your model, and the rest of the code that produces that table.